# Why is GraphQL mutation crashing app even when error is handled?

Tags: node.js, react-native, error-handling, graphql, apollo

I am stumped. My app keeps crashing when triggering a GraphQL mutation using `useMutation()`. I am catching the error using `onError()` and I have confirmed that the mutation is throwing the expected error.

Here is the mutation on the node.js server:

```
const signinWithPhone = async (obj, args, context) => {
  const { phone, authToken } = args;
  const { db } = context;
  // Find user
  const user = await db['users'].findOne({ phone });
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error('Phone number not found');
  }

  // Compare phone reset token
  const isTokenCorrect = await validatePhoneVerification(phone, authToken);
  if (!isTokenCorrect) {
    return null;
  }

  // Update last signin time without await
  const now = new Date().toISOString();
  db['users'].updateOne({ phone }, { $set: { lastLogin: now } });

  // Get token
  const token = await signToken(user);
  return { token, user, jwt: token, email: user.email, phone: user.phone };
};
```

And here is the corresponding React Native code:

```
const [signinWithPhone, { data }] = useMutation(SIGNIN_WITH_PHONE, {
    onError: (e) => {
      console.log('error');
      Alert.alert(e);
    },
  });

  const submitAuthToken = (code) => {
    setState({ ...state, authCode: code });
    console.log("hasn't crashed yet!");
    signinWithPhone({ variables: { phone, authToken: code } });
  };
```

It successfully prints out "hasn't crashed yet!" and "error" but then the app crashes.

Please help! Thanks.

### Solution

Figured it out. A couple of things I was doing wrong here. The bug wasn't in the useMutation function but how other data was being accessed after the call.

*Something* was being returned in the data obj, so `if(data)` was returning true and the app was crashing when I tried to access a property of data.

Additionally, the app was crashing when I tried to alert the user of the error. `Alert.alert(error)` does not work since it only accepts a string.

Comment: network error? check/show dev tools network response

Comment: `onError` does not _catch_ errors, it just executes some kind of side effect if the mutation fails. `data` can still be undefined. Can you maybe show more component code or provide more information about the error that crashes the app. You could e.g. use an error boundary to catch the error if it occurrs during the rendering.

Comment: solution should be written as an answer, you can answer your own question